# My post was edited but there are no changes

Tags: discussion, support

I am being careful here not to accuse anyone of anything in advance, maybe I am overlooking something.

I offered an answer to the question [Avoiding a colleague from my past](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56478/avoiding-a-colleague-from-my-past/)

A few minutes ago, I was informed that my answer has been edited. I was curious what exactly needed to be edited so I checked the edit info page. It claims that the editor "added 697 characters in body", and when I choose "side-by-side mark-down" it looks like that:

[image: Side-By-Side Mark-Down]

I did a diff check on my old version and the edited version and there just don't seem to be any changes, not even punctuation.

What happened here, what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that the editing user also edited the [main question with a quote from a now deleted response](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/56478/revisions) by the original poster, I'd guess that the edit was a case of mistaken identity. They had wanted to copy the text from the answer (now deleted) to edit in, did so, but accidentally first edited your post.

In that process there was an extra line break added at the end too ([original](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/56479/edit/af23ed87-1c2f-4414-8f4c-9f8ce8035f48) vs [revision](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/56479/edit/f423382f-876d-4908-a77f-0de4e1d45b79) ) that apparently super confused Stack Exchange into thinking the entire block was added. Or perhaps the first revision edited that paragraph out initially and then added back after they realized what they had accidentally done (and SE combined the edits).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Sounds messy, indeed. So, would it be ok then, or even desired that I roll back to my original answer?

Comment: @vic yeah, go for it!

Comment: Yeah, my guess would be a ninja-edit -- if somebody made a change and then made a second edit to manually undo it within the five-minute window, but it wasn't a 100% undo, I could see this happening.